# Bash Pipelined Shell scripts I wrote are Starved/Deadlocked/Performing poorly

Tags: bash, groovy, pipe, pipeline

I have used `duff` to create a report of duplicate files in my file system:

```
duff ~/Photos > ~/Photos/duplicates.txt
```

I have written some groovy scripts to transform this report into an HTML page where I can view the duplicate photos in my browser:

```
cat duplicates.txt | filter_non_existent.groovy | duff_to_json.groovy | json_to_html.groovy > duplicates.html
```

About 50% of the time, it works beautifully without any problems.

Other times some of my scripts don't start executing, or run very slowly. Why is this, and what can I do to prevent it? (and why don't "professionally written" command line programs like grep suffer from this problem?)

**More information**

- I delay the start of each script until it receives std input (while
  no data, sleep for 2.5 seconds). The starvation was more frequent
  when the sleep interval was shorter
- The more pipes I connect together, the more frequently it happens (if I just execute one of my scripts after `cat`, I never get the problem)
- Here's the template each of my scripts are using (I use the groovy runtime but stick to plain java syntax):

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  ```
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  while (!br.ready()) {
      Thread.sleep(2500L);
  }

  while (br.ready()) {
      String inputLine = br.readLine();
      // Do stuff
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you check if the stream is ready? All you want to do is wait for data to be available and read it when it is available; if you just use an ordinary potentially-blocking read, that is what will happen.

If you exit the read loop as soon as no data is immediately available, which is what your code excerpt seems to be doing, then it is likely that your program will terminate early, at least some of the time. If you just read (possibly blocking until data is available) until you see an EOF, then things should Just Work. (That is what grep and other "professionally written programs" do.)

Comment: Oh I see, I thought the `.ready()` would be equivalent to reading until it sees an EOF. I'll give this a try. (I was trying to avoid that horrible idiom where you assign to a loop variable inside a loop condition).

Comment: If the call to `ready` were equivalent to an EOF check, then retesting it after 2.5 seconds would be a bit silly, no? Pipes do not return EOF just because there's no data available; they return EOF when the (last) writer closes the file descriptor.

Comment: I'll have to mull over the common sense aspect you just mentioned. But until then, I'm happy to say this works :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say why with the limited info you've provided. Every time you pipe to another instance of groovy, you're starting up a new jvm, which has overhead and that will tax your system. (Check default startup settings for java.)

The other thing is your scripts sleep for 2.5 seconds, then poll for work, then go back to sleep for 2.5 seconds... If you have 3 scripts executing sequentially and one is waiting for output from the other, which is sleeping, etc. You can wait a maximum of:

2.5 + 2.5 + 2.5 = 7.5 seconds

Or longer if the work one of the other scripts has to do is longer than a second (like processing lots of Strings directly in java)... It may be worth your while to learn to use: bash, grep, etc. To first avoid re-inventing the wheel and second, use the right tool for the right job.

Groovy is great, but from what you're doing you can probably filter things with `grep -v` and for duff to json, json to html, maybe write ur adapter to go to html directly? Sounds like whatever you're doing to convert text is probably not very efficient...

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Regarding bypassing java/groovy altogether, I would rather not because this example just scratches the surface of the things I'd like to do which are easier to do in Java than bash. Also, I'm trying to prove to myself that giant enterprise Java applications are bad and that you can accomplish the same things more modularly with pipes (which hopefully I can impose when I gain more seniority later in my career).

Comment: Most giant enterprise java apps are bad, but shell, pipes and groovy scripts aren't necessarily the best approach to solve that problem. Google microservices